# Filling missing data by random choosing from non missing values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have a pandas data frame where there are a several missing values. I noticed that the non missing values are close to each other. Thus, I would like to impute the missing values by randomly choosing the non missing values.

For instance:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

foo = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 3, np.nan, 5, np.nan], 'B':[np.nan, 4, 2, np.nan, 5]})
foo
    A   B
0   2 NaN
1   3   4
2 NaN   2   
3   5 NaN
4 NaN   5
```

I would like for instance `foo['A'][2]=2` and `foo['A'][5]=3`
The  shape of my pandas DataFrame is (6940,154).
I try this

```
foo['A'] = foo['A'].fillna(random.choice(foo['A'].values.tolist()))
```

But it not working. Could you help me achieve that? Best regards.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `pandas.fillna` method and the `random.choice` method to fill the missing values with a random selection of a particular column.

```
import random
import numpy as np

df["column"].fillna(lambda x: random.choice(df[df[column] != np.nan]["column"]), inplace =True)
```

Where column is the column you want to fill with non `nan` values randomly.

Comment: I try it. But instead of imputing with the values it put  `<function <lambda> at 0x7fa4eb48b9b0>`..

Comment: sorry, can you provide some sample data?

Comment: I have edited my question with a sample data. Thanks

Comment: I have fund the answer. I did this : `foo = foo.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(random.choice(x.dropna())), axis=1)`. Your answer gave the clue. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: no worries. Glad I could help :) It was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 7):

This works well for me on Pandas DataFrame

```
def randomiseMissingData(df2):
    "randomise missing data for DataFrame (within a column)"
    df = df2.copy()
    for col in df.columns:
        data = df[col]
        mask = data.isnull()
        samples = random.choices( data[~mask].values , k = mask.sum() )
        data[mask] = samples

return df
```

Comment: For a pandas data frame this is a smart way of doing it as the statistics of the sample data reflects by definition the statistics of the original data. In this way you can fill the gaps while maintaining the same stats.

Comment: Better assign with `df.loc[mask, col] = samples` to avoid warnings

Answer (score 6):

I did this for filling NaN values with a random non-NaN value:

```
import random

df['column'].fillna(random.choice(df['column'][df['column'].notna()]), inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is another approach to this question after making improvement on the first answer and according to how to check if an numpy int is nand found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html)  in numpy documentation

```
foo['A'].apply(lambda x: np.random.choice([x for x in range(min(foo['A']),max(foo['A'])]) if (np.isnan(x)) else x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another Pandas DataFrame approach

```
import numpy as np
def fill_with_random(df2, column):
    '''Fill `df2`'s column with name `column` with random data based on non-NaN data from `column`'''
    df = df2.copy()
    df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(df[column].dropna().values) if np.isnan(x) else x)
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

for me only this worked, all the examples above failed.
Some filled same number, some didn't fill nothing.

```
def fill_sample(df, col):
    tmp = df[df[col].notna()[col].sample(len(df[df[col].isna()])).values
    k = 0
    for i,row in df[df[col].isna()].iterrows():

       df.at[i, col] = tmp[k]
       k+=1
    return df
```

Comment: Please don't embed code as a screenshot. Instead, paste it as text, and use Markdown to format it as code. That makes it easier to read, copy, and paste. It also helps ensure that it shows up in search results.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing and that worked was:

```py
foo = foo.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(random.choice(x.dropna())), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most concise, but probably the most performant way to go:

```
nans = df[col].isna()
non_nans = df.loc[df[col].notna(), col]
samples = np.random.choice(non_nans, size=nans.sum())
df.loc[nans, col] = samples
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing NaN with a random number from the range:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, np.nan, 4, np.nan, 6, 7, np.nan, 9]})

min_value = 0
max_value = 10

df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: np.random.randint(min_value, max_value) if pd.isnull(x) else x)

print(df)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't forget to format your code, using [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#:~:text=Code%20and%20Preformatted%20Text&text=You%20can%20also%20select%20text,other%20whitespace%20will%20be%20preserved.)