# Randomly Filling NaN values of a Column with Non-Null String Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with the following DataFrame containing `.str` values

```
maturity_rating
0   NaN
1   Rated: 18+ (R)
2   Rated: 7+ (PG)
3   NaN
4   Rated: 18+ (R)
```

and I'm trying to fill the NaN values randomly with other Non-Null values present in the same column

My expected output is:

```
maturity_rating
0   Rated: 7+ (PG)
1   Rated: 18+ (R)
2   Rated: 7+ (PG)
3   Rated: 18+ (R)
4   Rated: 18+ (R)
```

I tried using the following snippet

```
df["maturity_rating"].fillna(lambda x: random.choice(df[df['maturity_rating'] != np.nan]["maturity_rating"]), inplace =True)
```

However when I check for unique values, it fills NaN with a lambda object

```
df["maturity_rating"].unique()

Out[117]:
array([<function <lambda> at 0x7fe8d0431a60>, 'Rated: 18+ (R)',
       'Rated: 7+ (PG)', 'Rated: 13+ (PG-13)', 'Rated: All (G)',
       'Rated: 16+'], dtype=object)
```

Please Advise

Comment: [This comment has the working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36413314/filling-missing-data-by-random-choosing-from-non-missing-values-in-pandas-datafr#comment60443463_36413698)

Comment: Is there some rule as to how we fill na? YOu can look into pd.fillna and check the method argument for ffill, bfill etc..

Comment: @mck I've tried that method but it's got it's own issues for string values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us try [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
m = df['maturity_rating'].isna()
df.loc[m, 'maturity_rating'] = np.random.choice(df.loc[~m, 'maturity_rating'], m.sum())
```

**Details:**

Create a boolean mask using [`Series.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) which specifies the condition where `maturity_column` contains `NaN` values:

```
>>> m

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: maturity_rating, dtype: bool
```

Use boolean indexing with inverted mask `m` to select the non `NaN` elements from `maturity_rating` column then use [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) to randomly sample these elements:

```
>>> df.loc[~m, 'maturity_rating']

1    Rated: 18+ (R)
2    Rated: 7+ (PG)
4    Rated: 18+ (R)
Name: maturity_rating, dtype: object

>>> np.random.choice(df.loc[~m, 'maturity_rating'], m.sum())

array(['Rated: 18+ (R)', 'Rated: 7+ (PG)'], dtype=object)
```

Finally use boolean indexing to fill the `NaN` values in the `maturity_rating` column with the above sampled choices:

```
>>> df

  maturity_rating
0  Rated: 18+ (R)
1  Rated: 18+ (R)
2  Rated: 7+ (PG)
3  Rated: 18+ (R)
4  Rated: 18+ (R)
```