# Missing column values fill based on the available values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

How to fill missing values for apple `variety` from the **same column** when there are 1-4 varieties per farm and but cannot be two varieties with the same `ripening` index on the same farm? Assume the column has all possible scenarios.

For instance, in the below sample, '*Empire*' and *'Honeycrisp'* have the same `ripening` but they are from the different farms.

A sample `df` (a part of a larger dataframe):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'farm':   [419,382, 382, 382, 411, 411, 411],
         'variety': ['Gala', 'Gala', 'Empire', '', 'Honeycrisp', '', 'Fuji'],
         'ripening':[2,2,3,3,3,3,6],
         'D': np.random.randn(7)*10,
         'E': list('abcdefg')
         }
     )

df
Out[223]: 
   farm      variety  ripening          D  E
0    419        Gala         2  12.921246  a
1    382        Gala         2  -2.776150  b
2    382      Empire         3   3.551226  c
3    382                     3   2.715187  d
4    411  Honeycrisp         3 -13.557640  e
5    411                     3 -11.525100  f
6    411        Fuji         6  -3.660661  g
```

my desired output:

```
   farm      variety  ripening          D  E
0    419        Gala         2  12.921246  a
1    382        Gala         2  -2.776150  b
2    382      Empire         3   3.551226  c
3    382      Empire         3   2.715187  d
4    411  Honeycrisp         3 -13.557640  e
5    411  Honeycrisp         3 -11.525100  f
6    411        Fuji         6  -3.660661  g
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66406662/randomly-filling-nan-values-of-a-column-with-non-null-string-values) answer your question?

Comment: @Luke , it does but i like `df.update` below a lot more.  it also feels more "mainstream" comparing to `np.random.choice`, but obviously a matter of preference. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#create NaNs instead empty strings
df['variety'] = df['variety'].replace('', np.nan)

#test if only 1 unique category per ripening and farm
m = m = df.groupby(['farm','ripening'])['variety'].transform('nunique').eq(1)

#only for filtered rows forward filling values per groups
df.update(df[m].groupby(['farm','ripening'])['variety'].ffill())
print (df)
   farm     variety  ripening          D  E
0   419        Gala         2 -12.571434  a
1   382        Gala         2   1.839992  b
2   382      Empire         3  18.946881  c
3   382      Empire         3   6.552552  d
4   411  Honeycrisp         3  11.755782  e
5   411  Honeycrisp         3  11.272973  f
6   411        Fuji         6   7.416918  g
```